# How can i move the object using the keyboard?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d

I am trying to move the whole table to the left by pressing the h key on my keyboard, while also rotating the chair as if the the whole scene is moving to the right. But nothing seems to be happening. The glpushmatrix() and glpopmatrix() seem the most appropriate for this job. 
I tried "group" each whole object ( the chair and the table ) into groups composed of their respective structure using the auto [] function. 
Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

```
 #include <GLUT/GLUT.h>

char press;
int anglex,angley,x,y,xold,yold;
int angleHead = 0;



void display();
void keyboard(unsigned char touche,int x,int y);
void reshape(int x,int y);
void idle();
void mouse(int bouton,int etat,int x,int y);
void mousemotion(int x,int y);

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutCreateWindow("Scene");


    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glPointSize(2.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMotionFunc(mousemotion);


    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void display() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    auto chair = [] {
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef(-angley,1.0,0.0,0.0);
        glRotatef(-anglex,0.0,1.0,0.0);
        glPushMatrix();
        glScalef(0.15, 1.65, 0.6);
        glTranslatef(5, 0.0, 0.0);
        glutWireCube(0.5);
        glPopMatrix();
        glPushMatrix();
        glScalef(0.5, 0.2, 0.6);
        glTranslatef(1.18, -0.5, 0);
        glutWireCube(0.5);
        glPopMatrix();
        glScalef(0.2, 0.5, 0.6);
        glTranslatef(2.59, -0.55, 0);
        glutWireCube(0.5);
    };

    auto table =[] {
        glColor3f(0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef(-angley,1.0,0.0,0.0);
        glRotatef(-anglex,0.0,1.0,0.0);
        glPushMatrix();
        glScalef(1.5, 0.15, 0.6);
        glTranslatef(-0.055, 0.26, 0.0);
        glutWireCube(0.5);
        glPopMatrix();
        glPushMatrix();
        glScalef(0.15, 0.8, 0.6);
        glTranslatef(1.7, -0.25, 0.0);
        glutWireCube(0.5);
        glPopMatrix();
        glScalef(0.15, 0.8, 0.6);
        glTranslatef(-2.8, -0.25, 0.0);
        glutWireCube(0.5);

        auto box = [] {
            glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glRotatef(-angley,1.0,0.0,0.0);
            glRotatef(-anglex,0.0,1.0,0.0);
            glPushMatrix();
            glScalef(0.75, 0.2, 0.6);
            glTranslatef(-0.1, 0.65, 0.0);
            glutWireCube(0.5);
            glPopMatrix();
            glPushMatrix();
            glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            glScalef(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
            glTranslatef(0.1, 1, 0.0);
            glutWireSphere(0.4, 30, 30);
            glPopMatrix();
            glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            glScalef(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
            glTranslatef(-0.4, 1, 0.0);
            glutWireSphere(0.4, 30, 30);
        };
        box();

    };
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-0.5 - angleHead, 0.0, 0.0);
    chair();
    table();
    glPopMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glTranslatef(0.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    glScalef(7, 0.1, 5);
    glutWireCube(1);


    glutSwapBuffers();
}


void keyboard(unsigned char touche,int x,int y)
{

    if (touche =='h'){
            angleHead=angleHead + 0.5;
            glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

void reshape(int x,int y)
{
    if (x<y)
        glViewport(0,(y-x)/2,x,x);
    else
        glViewport((x-y)/2,0,y,y);
}

void mouse(int button, int state,int x,int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        press = 1;
        xold = x;
        yold=y;
    }

    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_UP)
        press=0; 
}

void mousemotion(int x,int y)
{
    if (press)
    {

        anglex=anglex+(x-xold);
        angley=angley+(y-yold);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }

    xold=x;
    yold=y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons nothing happens:

1. You add 0.5 to an int. An int represents *whole numbers*. So you basically add 0 at every increment of `angleHead`
2. After calling `glTranslatef()` you again call `glLoadIdentity()` which resets your translation in `glTranslatef()`

Comment: I tried adding an integer, and still nothing happened, i also tried removing the glLoadIdentity, and still nothing happened. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: You have to the glTranslate at the right moment, for example right before glRotatef depending on what you want to achieve